# Azure DevOps Server hangs when I try to deploy a release - What's the reason/remedy for this?

Tags: azure-devops

I cannot deploy a release in Azure DevOps Server (on-premise). Whenever I do, Azure DevOps Server shows a "loading" spinner and hangs:

[image: Can't publish release - 1]

The spinner is shown forever:

[image: Can't publish release - 2]

---

There are two other users in our team who share the same issue I have. I've been assigned Azure DevOps Server Administrator rights, still I cannot deploy, so it isn't a rights issue.

I've been logging into another Windows machine, been using other browsers ... yet, to no avail. I always get to see the spinner only.

**Strange enough**: Other users in our team can deploy releases in our project flawlessly. Currently, it's only three persons in our team who observe Azure DevOps Server hang. Even we could deploy releases until two weeks ago. No-one has changed anything. It suddenly stopped to work for three of us (me included).

I suppose it's a bug in Azure DevOps Server.

**What's causing this behaviour? How can we cope with it?**

EDIT:

These are the JavaScript warnings I get to see when using IE 11:

[image]

Comment: What steps are in the release? What is it trying to do? Is it waiting for an external resource? Do you get messages? Do other pipelines work? 
Based on the information 'the spinner is shown, why?' we cannot help you

Comment: Actually (as you can see from the screenshot) I cannot even reach the screen to **launch** deployment, so the actual steps it'll take don't apply yet. And (as you can see from the screenshot, too) I **don't** get any message. That's the meaning of "forever". Browser DevTools don't show any error. All I get to see in browser DevTools are numerous React warnings.

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolve this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue

Comment: Oh, I believed it was automatically marked as answer when I answer my own question myself. Thanks for pointing me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the error is based on the fact that we separated our boards from the repository in Azure DevOps.

In Azure DevOps we created a common board for all projects, but we left the projects themselves in their own Area. Then we moved the boards' items to the new overall board while we left the repositories at their original location (Area).

This seems to cause the hang when a repository's board gets disabled.

Re-enabling the repository's (now obsolete and redundant) board solves the issue.

[image: Azure DevOps: Enable Boards]